# Can I connect to Memgraph Cloud using Rust?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm wondering if I can connect from Rust to Memgraph Cloud. If it is important, I'm using a free version of the Memgraph Cloud at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a running Memgraph Cloud instance with Rust, you can use the provided code at the Cloud website. Also, the instructions are provided at the [Memgraph Cloud documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph-cloud/cloud-connect#rust).

Here are the steps:

1. Install mgclient - a C library interface for the Memgraph database ([installation instructions](https://github.com/memgraph/mgclient))
2. Add dependency to the `Cargo.toml` file:

```
rsmgclient = "0.1.1"
```

3. Copy the following code and add the host address, username and password, which can be found at Memgraph Cloud website:

```
use rsmgclient::{ConnectParams, Connection, SSLMode};

fn main(){
    // Parameters for connecting to database.
    let connect_params = ConnectParams {
        host: Some(String::from("MEMGRAPH_HOST_ADDRESS")),
        port: 7687,
        username: Some(String::from("YOUR_MEMGRAPH_USERNAME")),
        password: Some(String::from("YOUR_MEMGRAPH_PASSWORD")),
        sslmode: SSLMode::Require,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    // Make a connection to the database.
    let mut connection = match Connection::connect(&connect_params) {
        Ok(c) => c,
        Err(err) => panic!("Connect failed: {}", err)
    };

    // Execute a query.
    let query = "CREATE (n:FirstNode {message: 'Hello Memgraph from Rust!'}) RETURN id(n) AS nodeId, n.message AS message";
    match connection.execute(query, None) {
        Ok(c) => c,
        Err(err) => panic!("Query failed: {}", err)
    };

    match connection.fetchall() {
        Ok(records) => {
            println!("Created node: {}", &records[0].values[1])
        },
        Err(err) => panic!("{}", err)
    };
}
```